# If I found an answer to my question in another question, can I ask the OP for more information?

Tags: discussion

A lot of user are looking for answers to their questions on SO... If, while looking for their answer, they find some answer clues in a recently posted question, can they ask the original poster a question?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843796/listview-with-viewholder-textviews-change-content), from this question I want to know how to create a listitem background?

Comment: The comment is a comment on what a comment should be if it made any sense to be a comment.

Comment: @RBM I hope the edit makes sense to you... If I misunderstood the intent of your post feel free to roll it back or re-edit.

Comment: thanks @apaul34208 no that is fine..

Answer (score 6):

If you have a request for clarification from the author of a post, then you should post that question in a comment.  It doesn't sound like that's the case here through.

If you have a question to ask that is somewhat related to another question, or that is inspired by your reading of another question, then you should ask your own brand new question and simply include a link to the older "related" question.  Explain what it is that you want to know, and include enough of the relevant details from the related question to help clarify what it is you're asking about.

Comment: My question was clear that I found answer to my question in the mentioned question...that may be related to another question..but I haven't searched and I don't know other related question because I found answer in this recently posted question..

Comment: @RBM Well, no, that's not clear.  If you found a question that helped you answer a question that you had, upvote whatever posts helped you find that answer, and then move along.

Comment: @Servy But let us say that my question about the answer is not as questionable as I once thought.... My answers answer is a question to what a person can ask in answer form.

Comment: Nice...I haven't got any clues but inspired his question